# Why has no one told me I can use rubber lengths for graphics? Is that bad?

Tags: graphics, positioning, scaling

I just had a thought. Quite commonly when I define a figure graphics I write something like:

```
\begin{figure}[btp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth]
                    {example.png}
    \caption{foo bar buzz}
\end{figure}
```

But today, it struck me, that I can do:

```
\begin{figure}[btp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth plus 0.05\textwidth minus 0.05\textwidth]
                    {example.png}
    \caption{foo bar buzz}
\end{figure}
```

Why has noone told me about this before? :)

And more importantly, are there any good reasons not to do this?

EDIT: Just to clarify, my thought was that this would be used to avoid widows and orphans. But maybe that doesn't even work?

Comment: Your code doesn't work for me. I get a "missing number" error. Beside this I doubt that it would do anything useful.

Comment: Nobody told you because it doesn't do what you would: you can't give a box a dimension that's a rubber length.

Comment: As @egreg notes it doesn't work, but even for things that do allow stretch such as `\hspace*{5pt plus 5pt}` this is horizontal stretch do has no effect on widow or orphan control which is about page breaking, so needs to affect vertical stretch.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Nobody told you because, simply, you *can't* do it.

This runs without error:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=10pt plus 10pt minus 2pt]{example-image.pdf}
\end{document}
```

but this is not a sign that it does something according to your wish. Indeed, it's sufficient to look at the output:

[image]

Your code

```
\includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth plus 0.05\textwidth minus 0.05\textwidth]
```

makes TeX stop with

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \def
```

that's due to some `\csname` construction that finds `\textwidth` before `\endcsname` and this token is illegal in that context.

What's the problem? The length you specify for `width` is used to set the width of a box and a box has a fixed width. Rubber lengths are used for specifying *glue* that can shrink or stretch.

Comment: Hm so I can not get TeX to change the size of boxes in order to avoid widows and orphans. That explains a lot... It's as usual, if something seems too good to be true it probably is...

Comment: @jonalv It also helps to try it first. :)

Comment: @JasonC: That's a very good point! My TeX did slurp it though. I wonder if that calc package or LuaTeX or something might have changed something and make it slurp it. I thought it worked but I realize now that my test wasn't exactly bullet-proof :)